# Using Chapman-Kolmogorov Property to prove v=Qv

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

How would you use the Chapman-Kolmogorov property ($Q_{t+s}=Q_tQ_s$) to prove that v (a column vector distribution over the sample space) is a stationary distribution of Markov Chain $X_t$ with transition matrix $Q$ if $v=Qv$?